# Show all conflicting files in Android Studio GUI

Tags: git, android-studio, version-control

Is there a way to show all conflicting files in Android Studio? I am thinking of some view/list that will only show the conflicting ones.

Currently I am finding them manually by looking into terminal output after running `git merge` and opening the ones that were not auto-merged one by one.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

You can merge branches by the option in Android Studio -> VCS -> Git -> merge changes.

Then you will get the files with conflicts.

[image]

If you close the merge conflicts windows, you can also get the list of conflict files under the vseriojn control Tab.

[image]

Answer (score 19):

In Android Studio, you can go to VCS > Git > Resolve conflicts. It will show you all the conflicting files and you can select what to keep and what to drop with a great GUI. Hope it's the answer you were looking for.

Comment: That's what I'm looking for.

Comment: this is greyed out for me, I don't know why, i'm using SourceTree, there must be some integration step i'm missing...

Comment: i hadn't installed GIT :)

Answer (score 1):

This is a good question, and I would have also gone the route you did, namely opening the Git bash doing `git status`.  I don't know of a direct way to get a list of all files in conflict, but there is a proxy which should work equally well.  Simply do a find in all source files for anyone of the following three merge conflict markers:

```
>>>>>>>
=======
<<<<<<<
```

Ideally your source files won't contain these markers unless Git just put them there.  At the bottom of Android studio you should have a list of matching files which should also be the list of files which have merge conflicts.

There may be a more direct way to do this in Android Studio, but this trick might be very helpful to someone using a less heavyweight IDE like Sublime.